# Notepad all line replace with integer values

Tags: notepad++

Hi i have 270 line in the file and lines is:
I would like to replace all line with notepad++

```
bokor[0] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 26.74608, -115.42576, 1.26719, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
bokor[0] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 21.22019, -114.57922, 1.19473,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
bokor[0] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 15.78675, -113.58897, 1.19854,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
bokor[0] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 10.23538, -112.18955, 1.30028,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
.
.
. <---- 269 pieces
.
.
bokor[0] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 3.96403, -18.49982, 3.58015,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
```

And how to replace all piece to:

```
bokor[0] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 26.74608, -115.42576, 1.26719, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
bokor[1] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 21.22019, -114.57922, 1.19473,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
bokor[2] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 15.78675, -113.58897, 1.19854,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
bokor[3] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 10.23538, -112.18955, 1.30028,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
.
.
. <---- 269 pieces
.
.
bokor[273] = CreateDynamicObject(821, 3.96403, -18.49982, 3.58015,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
```

Sorry i have bad english skill.

Comment: one by one rewrite

Comment: but there is a such a code in which the same lines have been 2000 sorry i have bad english

Comment: Your english is not the problem :) But please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: Sorry but im a new user. I will watch it but you have some idea of the notepad problem ?

Comment: I solved this problem